# Modeling the Objective Function in the CPLEX Java API

Tags: java, cplex, operations-research

I#m trying to model the objective function **sum(i in Sites,j in Sites, k in Routings)(c[i][j] * x[i][j][k]*TruckKmCost)** in Cplex using java.

```
IloLinearNumExpr expr = cplex.linearNumExpr();
            for (int i = 1; i <= nbFarmer; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= nbFarmer; j++) {
                    for (int k = 1; k <= nbRouting; k++) {
                  expr.addTerm(truckKmCost, c[i][j],x[i][j][k]);   
               }
            }
}
```

This was my attempt, but the method addTerm only accepts (double, IloNumVar), and I can't convert c[i][j] to IloNumVar, because I need it as an int so i can add my int values to it.

There must be a pretty easy solution, maybe somebody can help me, I'm a little stumped right now.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify whether `c[i][j]` is a variable or a number. Depending on this there are two different solutions to your issue:

1. In case `c[i][j]` is a number then just write `expr.addTerm(truckKmCost * c[i][j], x[i][j][k])`, that is, merge the two numbers into one single argument to `addTerm`.
2. In case `c[i][j]` is a variable then your objective is not linear but quadratic. In that case you cannot use `IloLinearNumExpr` but have to use `IloQuadNumExpr`. The `addTerm()` of this class takes two variables as arguments.